# Combining two indexes (column names?) from same table into 1?

Tags: python, pandas

I am utilizing a pivot to roll up data. The data is of the form:

```
year    month    name
2012    1        annie
2012    1        annie
2012    2        david
2012    2        david
2012    2        david
```

I use the the following code to create a pivot:

```
date_pivot = pd.pivot_table(date_pivot, index=['name'], columns=['year','month'], aggfunc=len)
```

Which aggregates that data into the form:

```
year    2012
month   1        2
name    
annie   2        0
david   0        3
```

Meaning I think that the column names are split up into like two seperate parts. I am wanting to combine these into a single column name of the form:

```
2012.1    2012.2
```

Such that I can later define some ranges of the column names. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create another column with the values you're looking for, and then pivot based on that column.

```
date_pivot['year_month'] = date_pivot['year'].map(str) + "." + date_pivot['month']
date_pivot = pd.pivot_table(date_pivot, index=['name'], columns=['year_month'], aggfunc=len)
```

**EDIT**

You will probably want to pad your months with `zfill(2)` when creating the new column so that your columns sort properly. Otherwise `2012.10` will sort before month `2012.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the columns and assgin it back

```
date_pivot.columns=list(map('{0[0]}.{0[1]}'.format, date_pivot.columns.values.tolist()))
date_pivot
Out[266]: 
       2012.1  2012.2
name                 
annie     2.0     NaN
david     NaN     3.0
```